# Does OS X support disk compression?

Tags: macos, ntfs, compression

I am new to the Mac world.

As you may know, NTFS has options to "Compress this drive to save disk space" or "Compress contents to save disk space".

I want to know whether OS X supports this feature and to what extent.

Comment: Are you talking about disk compression in general, or specifically OSX's support for NTFS' compression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090902223042255), HFS+ compression was introduced with OS X Snow Leopard.

> So to compress a file or directory with HFS+ compression, all you should usually need to do is type ditto --hfsCompression [src] [dst] into the Terminal, replacing [src] with the path to the source file/directory, and [dst] with the path to the destination file/directory.

You can also use apps such as [Clusters](http://latenitesoft.com/clusters/), [MoreSpace](http://www.merlindevs.com) and so on. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50525/creating-an-automated-hfs-compressed-folder) Ask Different thread might also be of interest to you.

Comment: Does this compress the entire disk? Or just selected files? The great thing about NTFS compression is it applies to the disk, not any files. It is transparent to programs and applications and fully managed by Windows in the background. The files show as regular files, not compressed archives such as ZIP or RAR. They are openable in the default application as though they were never compressed. Windows decompresses and recompresses the file in the background (the application doesn't know, and the user doesn't care). **Can Mac OS X do something similar?**

Comment: `HFS Compression` isn't convenient as NTFS Compression on Windows in my experience.

 @Karan mentioned some apps, but they aren't working properly on my system and seems obsolete.

If your system runs out on SSD/HDD spaces, it can be done with some command line works for specific folders you want, it's not for entire disk compression like  Windows.